# How can I figure out what button was clicked on last?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

How can I figure out what button was clicked on last? For example I have:

```
<input type="button" name= "zoomer" value="State View" id= 'States View' onclick="zoomout()"/>
<input type="button" name= "zoomer" value="County View" id= 'Counties View' onclick="countyView()"/>
```

But whenever I change a RADIO button, I want it to take into account which button was clicked last (County View or State View). Is it possible to do this?

Comment: for some reason your code didn't post...

Comment: Just edited and put the code in.

Comment: I do not understand the reference to radio buttons. It might help if you posted some javascript code.

Comment: Why not put a state variable itemLastChanged or something in your onclick methods...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep a global JavaScript variable `var last_clicked` which is updated in the functions `zoomout()` and `countyView()`, and then check the value of `last_clicked` when you change the radio button. Alternatively, you can terminate the calls to the functions within the `onclick` event with a semicolon, then assign the value to `last_clicked` inside the `onclick` event string (although I wouldn't recommend it as it can make your code messy).

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastClicked = "none";

function zoomout()
{
    // your code
    lastClicked = "states";
}

function countyView()
{
    //your code
    lastClicked = "county";
}

if(lastClicked == "county")
{

}
else if(lastClicked == "states")
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's possible by using an external variable such as

```
var clickedLast = "";

function zoomout() {
  clickedLast = "stateview";
  ... your code ...
}

function countyView() {
  clickedLast = "countyview";
  ... your code ...
}
```